# How to add classes to select tags using Html->control() in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Does someone know how to add classes to select tags ? Please help me!

I have at the moment:

```
<?= $this->Form->control(
              'tutor_profile.birthday',
              [
                'empty' => 'Choose...',
                'minYear' => date('Y') - 100,
                'maxYear' => date('Y')
              ]
            );
            ?>
```

The select tags are created as follows:

```
<select name="tutor_profile[birthday][year]">...</select>
<select name="tutor_profile[birthday][month]">...</select>
<select name="tutor_profile[birthday][day]">...</select>
```

But I want them to be like this :

```
<select name="tutor_profile[birthday][year]" class="myClass">...</select>
<select name="tutor_profile[birthday][month]" class="myClass">...</select>
<select name="tutor_profile[birthday][day]" class="myClass">...</select>
```

I tried adding `['class' => 'myClass']` but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom class to CakePHP automagic date select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318376/add-custom-class-to-cakephp-automagic-date-select)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $this->Form->control(
    'tutor_profile.birthday',
    [
        'empty' => 'Choose...',
        'minYear' => date('Y') - 100,
        'maxYear' => date('Y'),
        'class' => 'myClass', // <-------
    ]
  );?>
```

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L155

```
'select' => '<select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>',
```

**{{attrs}}**

- 'id' => 'my_id'
- 'class' => 'my_class'
- 'data-custom' => 'custom value'
- ...

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-controls